# Return generic collection from getter

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a problem with returning generic collection from getter method. My class looks like this:

```
public abstract class ContentGroup<E extends Content> extends Content {

    private List<E> childContents = new LinkedList<E>();

    public List<E> getChildContents() {
        return childContents;
    }
    ...
}

public class Container extends ContentGroup {

}
```

When I call `getChildContents()` method it returns a list, but not a list of objects extending `Content` class so I have to explicitly cast returned value to `Content`:

```
public void doit(Container contentGroup) {

    //Why does get method return Object instead of Content?
    Content content = (Content) contentGroup.getChildContents().get(0); 
    ...
}
```

**Edit**

I updated the code to reflect better the acctual implementation. As one of the answers suggests the problem was that Container did not define Type. Problem was solved with:

```
public class Container extends ContentGroup<Content> {

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: `do` is a keyword in Java. Can't be used as identifier (method name)

Comment: What if you change the signature to `_do(ContentGroup<?> contentGroup)` ?

Comment: share complete code where this method is defined.

Comment: I changed method invocation fragment to simplify code (unfortunately from infinite number of possibilities to name a method I picked java keyword). Already edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed *Generic* with [*Raw Type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Have a look at the method arguments, It's not Generic.

```
public void do(ContentGroup contentGroup) { // RAW type is used
```

It should be generic as well otherwise at runtime you would encounter an exception while casting.

Comment: It solves the problem I was missing type in class deriving from ContentGroup (see updated code). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To complete user3218114's answer, you should do something like this:

```
class Content {
}

class ExtendedContent extends Content {

    void foo() {
    }
}

abstract class ContentGroup<E extends Content> extends Content {

    private List<E> childContents = new LinkedList<E>();

    public List<E> getChildContents() {
        return childContents;
    }
}

class ExtendedContentGroup extends ContentGroup<ExtendedContent> {
}

public class Toto {

    public <E extends Content> E toto(ContentGroup<E> contentGroup) {
        return contentGroup.getChildContents().get(0); 
    }

    public void bar() {
        ExtendedContent extendedContent = toto(new ExtendedContentGroup());
        extendedContent.foo();
    }
}
```

Also note that I did get a compilation error because **do is a reserved word in Java** (could come from my IDE settings though, not 100% sure of that), so I suspect you should rename your function (toto in my case).

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I had to do. Already accepted user3218114's answer.